# Is there a friction or retarding force in creating spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, space-expansion, big-bang

As matter and energy expand with the big bang, they create spacetime (or so I've been told).  Is there any evidence that this creation of spacetime has a retarding force on the expansion?  If not, does this mean that matter moves through (existing) space with the same ease and when it is expanding space?  That seems unusual. Gravity is a retarding force, but that force exists in normal (already created) space as well.  I'm wondering if there is any force due to the creation of spacetime.

Comment: Side note, existing space *is* expanding space. It's the same space. Expansion is more like stretching than it is like adding new space

Comment: So space already exists everywhere out to infinity? And always has? That seems remarkably convenient....

Comment: It's just as convenient as it starting out of nothing and new space being constantly created

Comment: But that would mean infinite space was here before the big bang.  I find that remarkable.

Comment: No, that's not at all what it means. It only means infinite space was created at the big bang

Comment: That's even worse....

Comment: does this old argument make any sense? If space only has meaning as a measure of the distance between two or more objects, then because presumably before the B.B. there were no objects so the concept of space is meaninglessness.  Please feel free to ignore this comment as  philosophical wordplay if you feel it is invalid, but it sometimes works if I am trying to explain the creation of spacetime to anyone who is interested.

Comment: Given that gravity warps spacetime, I don't think its meaningless, even if there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity is the retarding force. I don't think that non-conservative forces are customarily considered.

Comment: Gravity is not considered a force at those scales so much as it is simply the curvature of spacetime due to the various forms of energy. And while it *does* allow the deceleration of the expansion when in concert with matter or radiation, it also allows the acceleration of the expansion when sourced by dark energy. So the only thing I can say is this answer is not even wrong

Comment: Added to the question to clarify the matter.  Not really thinking about gravity, but thanks for pointing that out to help me clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regular matter and energy, through, gravity tends to slow the expansion. I do not know of any theory that treats it or any other "retarding" force as friction. However there is evidence that another stuff in the universe, different from regular matter and energy (called dark energy) is actually accelerating the expansion, rather than slowing it (also, through gravity) .

And in current theories yes, matter moves through (existing) space with the same ease than through expanding space

Comment: Gravity is the curvature of spacetime. Dark energy accelerates the expansion as a negative pressure term that curves spacetime such that expansion accelerates. This means dark energy, like all other forms of energy, affects expansion through gravity

Comment: @Jimnosperm thanks for the clarification, I corrected my answer.